# Show me unanswered questions in my area of expertise

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

In an effort to put the right eyes on the questions that need answering, I'd love to see a control on the "unanswered" tab which allows you to filter the list by the tags under the "My Tags" section of my profile.

**This would allow for users to see a list of all the unanswered questions only in the areas of their expertise.**



*I spend a lot of time digging through "Unanswered."*      =)

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags

Comment: Each tag-page already has a 'unanswered' tab. You can use the `[tag1] [or] [tag2] [or] [tag3] ...` search feature to create a tag page for a group of tags.

Comment: I guess the functionality of *?tab=mytags* never really occurred to me as it shows me about 95k questions.  I feel like a noob, sorry for requesting existing features.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on *Unanswered questions* and then on *My Tags* to view the list you wanted.

[image]